duplicated ID shown to the user when the submitted the form at the same time
I'm trying to create a form for my employees to submit their tickets using Google forms.
The user is going to receive the ticket id as a confirmation message, and Google sheets will show the ticket id for the moderation team to reference.
The problem is that if it received two submissions at the same time then the user is going to get the same ticket id and the two rows will be empty.

Code:
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const idColumn = 1;
  
  // const ticketID = 'T-' + Utilities.formatString('%04d', lastRow);
  const ticketID = lastRow
  const currentID = lastRow + 1
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, idColumn).setValue(ticketID);

  Logger.log('New ticket ID: ' + ticketID);
  
  const form = FormApp.openById('1oxTnzU5NRnzAlNFMmyehSf9vkORLs9vj5-XGGDvfqM0');  
  const message = 'Thank you! Your ticket number is: ' + currentID;
  form.setConfirmationMessage(message);
}


I would incorporate a UUID or timestamp into the id.

Where is this code? The ID should be generated server-side, which is how you can know that you truly have a unique ID.

Use Event Objects... rowStart will be unique; use it as a substitute for 'lastRow'.

form.setConfirmationMessage(message); Oops - I think you are trying to be too smart by half. Better to send an email with the ticket number than try to maintain the confirmation message.
